# way my appbarlayout is covered by my fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

In my app, I have a NavigationDrawer Menu which must be displayed in all my app pages, so I must use fragment. Now, I create a navigation drawer project template and here is my layouts:
**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    tools:openDrawer="right">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**and this is my app_bar_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.techers.dayan.dayan.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frgContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.techers.dayan.dayan.UIfragment.MainFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is my fragment view xml file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.techers.dayan.dayan.UIfragment.MainFragment">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="587dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
            android:id="@+id/slider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"/>


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtSearch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:hint="جستجو"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxHeight="30dp"
            android:minHeight="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            tools:layout_width="match_parent"
            tools:minHeight="30dp"
            tools:textAlignment="gravity" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridProduct"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Finally, this is result:[image]

As you see my fragment covers my appBarLayout. how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: that might be a problem with toolbar java code (add it)

Comment: remove the hard-code height of Linear Layout 587dp and Cover you <fragment with android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.

Comment: You could use a RelativeLayout in your main activity and set layout_below on your fragment in order to set it below your toolbar.

Comment: it work for me..... tnx dude

Comment: please add your comment as answer to mark it or solution

Answer (score 0):

You should add this line of code `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in your fragment xml declaration, that should position it directly below the appbar; you can read more about that [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) under the **CoordinatorLayout and the app bar** section

```
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/frgContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:name="com.techers.dayan.dayan.UIfragment.MainFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"/>
```

The code above should do the trick

EDIT: changed the code sample, now it should work (tested locally on xml AS preview)

Comment: it cannot recognize app namespace in this xml

Comment: it does not change any thing for me.

Comment: This is because it's a property form the support library, add this extra line of code below xmlns:tools"...." to include it

`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`